# Capybara/Poltergeist pick range of numbers for all text boxes?

Tags: rspec, capybara

I have a series of text boxes on a page, that are intended for a numerical value (lets say 1-10). It's less important at what the ratings are, but just that they are something between 1-10 (ideally a random number between these would be ideal)

Is there any way I can grab ALL of the text boxes from the page and fill them in with a random number?

The HTML for ONE text box looks like this:

```
<td class="surface">
 <div class="form-group integer optional test_the_rating">
  <input id="test_0_rating" class="numeric integer optional form-control" type="number" name="test[the][0][rating]" step="1" data-filter-class="review" data-rate="0" max="10" min="1">
 </div>
</td>
```

It's this repeated X times (it differs per page, but it's 5 of them in the particular page im looking at)

Could something like this work: (the table--questions is the name of the table itself)

```
page.all('table.table--questions tbody tr div', minimum: 5).each do |row|
     row.all("test_the_rating").something?
end
```

i'll probably need to use the text box class which is `test_the_rating` since there are also buttons as well on this row of information (that are irrelevant to this test) but they are on the same row as this text box.

I figured maybe I could use Ruby's sample I know works with this? something like: `[*1..10].sample`? Would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things here --

1. You state that 'table--questions' is the 'name' of the table but are using it as a class selector -- if it truly is the value of a 'name' attribute on the table you'd want `table[name="table-questions"]`
2. You state you want ALL the text boxes, but your html shows them to actually be "number" boxes.  If you do want all the number boxes you could just do something like

   ```
   page.all(:field, nil, type: 'number', minimum: 5).each do |inp|  #The nil parameter may not be needed depending on the version of Capybara you're using
    inp.set(rand(1..10).to_s)
   end
   ```

Comment: expected to find field nil of type :number at least 5 times but there were no matches. Also found "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", which matched the selector but not all filters.   (thats the error I get using this). 

Thats the error I get with that. Im not sure if what it's referring to is maybe the other row fields ( comment sections and such)

Comment: @msmith1114 What version of Capybara are you using? and are there at least 5 fields actually visible on the page?

Comment: @msmith1114 -- whoops -- type parameter should be a string -- fixed in example

Comment: yes all 5 fields are visible (the numerical fields)

Comment: @msmith1114 Did you change the type parameter from a symbol to a string like I fixed in the example?

Comment: Wow nice it worked, im not sure i understand how/what changed and what exactly it means (i've never seen the inp before)

Comment: @msmith1114 inp is just a variable -- `all(:field, nil, type: 'number', minimum: 5)` uses the  :field selector -  https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/2.7_stable/lib/capybara/selector.rb#L108 - to find all visible input/textarea/select elements that have attribute type == 'number' (the type filter)- then calls `each` on the array like result of that, assigning each field in turn to the variable `inp` and setting that field to a random value of 1 to 10